# How to pass value to a viewController embedded in NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

There are similar questions but they are either in swift or are not solving my problem.
I've a view controller which is presenting navigation view controller when cell did select button is pressed as:

```
patientBillNavigationViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PatientBillVC"];
//soem value assignment
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You can say billing opens up a whole new view independent of the main app flow to handle billing process.

The view this navigation View Controller automatically loads is the bill view and now if I want to pass a value from this viewcontroller to the other viewController embedded in navigation view I can't do that. How to pass a value?

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
            PatientBillViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PBVC"];

            vc.superBillToAddEdit = sb;
//then display the view embedded in navigation view
```

But this is not working.

Comment: why don't you use `delegate protocol` for that? Set the view controller as the delegate of your `PatientBillViewController` before presenting it.

Answer (score 1):

One way I know is to Subclass `UINavigationViewController` and in its `viewDidLoad`, you can do:

```
 YourEmbeddedVc *svc =self.viewControllers[0]; //get the controller reference
 svc.name= @"Hello";
```

I'm assuming you are only having one controller in your navigation stack, if not you need to find out the proper match of the required VC.

Answer (score 1):

I might not be understanding the question exactly, correct me if I'm wrong.

It sounds like you want to start a nav controller from a view controller (let's call this `firstViewController`) and pass a value from `firstViewController` to the view controller that will eventually load in the nav controller.

If that's the case, why don't you create the second view controller (`billingStep1ViewController`) and then assign the value to it as a property, then pass the billingStep1ViewController to the nav controller's `initWithRootViewController:` method?

<strike>Something like this (untested code, btw):</strike>

```
// this code would go inside our FirstViewController file
// create the first vc that will be loaded in the nav controller
BillingStep1ViewController *billingStepOneVc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"stepOne"];
// set the value you want
billingStepOneVc.bill = myBill;
// create new nav controller with step one vc as the root
UINavigationController *uiNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:billingStepOneVc];
[self presentViewController:uiNavController];
```

That way you can have two view controllers talking directly with one another and not worry about the navigation controller at all.

**Update**: Here is some *tested* code that works to illustrate my idea:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
//create the step 1 view controller - this is the first view controller we will see in the navigation controller
StepOneViewController *stepOneVc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"stepOne"];
//assign a value to it (name is an NSString @property of StepOneViewController)
stepOneVc.name = @"Jones";

//this is the nav controller we will display, we set the root vc to our step one.
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:stepOneVc];

//present the nav controller on screen.
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Some of the class names changed but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating the navigation controller from its storyboard identifier, create it programmatically, with the `PatientBillViewController` you created as its root view controller. Like this:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

PatientBillViewController *pbVC = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PBVC"];
pbVC.superBillToAddEdit = sb;

PatientBillNavigationViewController * navVC = [[PatientBillNavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pbVC];

[self presentViewController:navVC animated:true completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Version**

Here is the swift version answer for the above problem!!

```
   let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PatientBillVC") as! patientBillNavigationViewController
   vc.name = "name"
   let mVc = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc)
       self.navigationController?.present(mVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```